# Sending data to a web Server

Tags: ios, iphone, database, webserver

I've created a program that send's a data to a webserver. I used the NSURLConnection to send the data to the web server. I've created a php file on my server to handle all the POST request from the iPhone. My question was are there any other ways to send the data to a web Server besides using WiFi connection. I just only need to send small data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are there any other ways to send the
>   data to a web Server besides using
>   wifi connection

Yes, EDGE and 3G